# If some agency has too many responsibilities, how do you describe it?

Tags: word-request

If some agency has too many competencies, things it's responsible for, what adjective can I use? For example, if it's an intelligence, counter-intelligence, law enforcement body all at once (with the expectation that these functions are supposed to be carried out by separate entities). 'Overblown (authority/responsibilities)'? 'Overreaching'? 'Excessive powers' is dull, I don't want to use it.

Comment: You probably want "responsibilities" rather than "competencies". Competencies are things that an entity is good at doing (or at least competent at doing).

Comment: **conflicting responsibilities** is often used.

Comment: @Lambie What if I want to stress that there are too many of them, not that they conflict with each other?

Comment: overburdened with responsibilities, top heavy

Comment: @Lambie 'Overburdened' implies that the agency is not pleased with it and would prefer to have some of the responsibilities lifted. What if it's not the case?

Answer (score 1):

The best word depends on what is trying to be conveyed. Some possibilities include:

"Overburdened" means trying to do too many things at once, to the point that its capabilities and performance suffer as a result. Originally it meant carrying to much weight (for example, a horse that can carry only one rider being saddled with two riders).

"Overreaching" means going beyond its limits (these might be legal limits, or physical limits). So, for example, if an agency that was only given authority in the area of counter-intelligence spread into active intelligence gathering, and then domestic law enforcement, it might said to be "overreaching".

"Overblown" is used to mean "made to seem more than it is to an excessive degree" or "pretentious" (it originally meant, and can still mean in some contexts, to be over inflated, like a balloon or tire that has had air blown into it to a near-bursting point).

Comment: I mean if an agency has too many legally provided responsibilities. None of your words seems to fit. It's not a burden, it's powers it's happy to have but shouldn't

Comment: An agency can be overburdened. Sure. The other two don't work for this context.

Answer (score 0):

The organization has **disparate areas of responsibility**.

[disparate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disparate), from MW:

> containing or made up of fundamentally different and often incongruous elements